# Ansible fails after changing ansible_python_interpreter

Tags: python, ansible

After changing the default python path ansible cannot run or load any python library

```
{  
   "changed":false,
   "failed":true,
   "module_stderr":"Shared connection to x.x.x.x closed.\r\n",
   "module_stdout":"Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/home/user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1510222878.61-64380131096787/setup.py\", line 123, in <module>\r\n    f.write(z.read('ansible_module_setup.py'))\r\n  File \"/home/user/python/lib/p`enter code here`ython2.7/zipfile.py\", line 935, in read\r\n    return self.open(name, \"r\", pwd).read()\r\n  File \"/home/user/python/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py\", line 1010, in open\r\n    close_fileobj=should_close)\r\n  File \"/home/user/python/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py\", line 526, in __init__\r\n    self._decompressor = zlib.decompressobj(-15)\r\nAttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decompressobj'\r\n",
   "msg":"MODULE FAILURE",
   "rc":0
}
```

i've also tried to run ansible -m ping i get pretty much the same result

```
{  
   "changed":false,
   "failed":true,
   "module_stderr":"Shared connection to x.x.x.x closed.\r\n",
   "module_stdout":"Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/home/user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1510223942.9-58678212493208/ping.py\", line 123, in <module>\r\n    f.write(z.read('ansible_module_ping.p 
y'))\r\n  File \"/home/user/python/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py\", line 935, in read\r\n    return self.open(name, \"r\", pwd).read()\r\n  File \"/home/user/python/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py\", line 1010, in open\r\
n    close_fileobj=should_close)\r\n  File \"/home/user/python/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py\", line 526, in __init__\r\n    self._decompressor = zlib.decompressobj(-15)\r\nAttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no a
ttribute 'decompressobj'\r\n",
   "msg":"MODULE FAILURE",
   "rc":0
}
```

ansible 2.3.2.0

python 2.7.11

any help would be very much appreciated !

Comment: Why did you expect it to work?  Why did you change it to begin with?

Comment: well changing the default python interpreted is common + there are two version of python installed on the machine, some of ansible modules (maven_artifact) expects some dependencies ( lxml ) and those dependencies work with at least python v2.7

Comment: You just found out why it's a bad idea to have two version of Python installed.

Comment: well i figured that would create a problem but is there an alternative to work with two versions installed ?

Comment: Depends on versions.  You can handle Python 2 vs. Python 3 with `virtualenv`, `pyenv`, or equivalent.  You still need to understand what you're doing, and not fight the system's package manager.

Comment: there is a default python version installed v2.6.6 and i installed another one v2.7.11 for the user i'm using when i type python --version it gives me 2.7.11 as the used python ( i'm made sure that the $PATH variable is using the correct version of python for the user ) so besides all of that i'm not understading why the versions are overlapping

Comment: Because your Ansible was installed with modules for 2.6 and you're trying to use it with 2.7.

Comment: in ansible you can configure the python version used by the tool using the ansible_python_interpreter variable

Comment: ... Which doesn't mean changing it without reinstalling the relevant modules makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI - Issue raised - https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/25941

Linked to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47199770/ansible-fails-after-changing-ansible-python-interpreter